# Unexpected `LinearRecurrence` behavior in 13.2

Tags: bugs, recursion

From the definitions, I expect `LinearRecurrence[{1}, {k}, 10]` to be a constant array.

```
LinearRecurrence[{1}, {1}, 10]
(*{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}*)
LinearRecurrence[{1}, {k}, 10]
(*{k, k, k, k, k, k, k, k, k, k}*)
```

When the third argument is with brackets, it should output the `n` th term.

```
LinearRecurrence[{1}, {k}, {10}]
(*{k}*)
```

However, when I replace `k` with an actual number

```
LinearRecurrence[{1}, {1}, {10}]
(*{2}*)
```

Can anyone help with providing explanations for this behavior?
I am using Mathematica 13.2 on macOS 13.3.1

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I would report it to: support@wolfram.com